Request in getting the general expression.
Given a dartboard, of radius 'r', with 5 concentric circles, with numbering starting from the outermost one, from 1. The distance between each ring is 'r/5'.

Assuming that the board is always hit, then we have the probability of the dart hitting a particular region is proportional to the area of the region.
Then, probability of scoring i points: P(i) =  $\frac{ Area\ of \ region \ i}{                                               Area \ of \ the \ dart  \ board}$
For example, the probability of scoring 1 points is given by:
$$\frac{\pi \cdot (r^2 - (\frac{4r}5)^2)}{\pi \cdot r^2} = \boxed{1- (\frac{4}5)^2}$$
Or, the probability of scoring 2 points is given by;
$$\frac{\pi \cdot (r^2 - (\frac{3r}5)^2 - (1 - (\frac{4r}5)^2))}{\pi \cdot r^2} = 1- (\frac{3}5)^2 -(1- (\frac{4}5)^2) = {1- \frac{9}{25} -1 + \frac{16}{25}} = \boxed{\frac{7}{25}}$$
alternatively, can find by:
$$\frac{\pi \cdot (r^2 - (\frac{3r}5)^2}{\pi \cdot r^2} - \frac{9}{25}= 1- (\frac{3}5)^2 -\frac{9}{25} = \boxed{\frac{7}{25}}$$
Request to point how to derive the general expression for the same, as is given as:
$$\frac{(6-i)^2 - (5-i)^2}{5^2}, i =1, 2, \cdots,5$$
but am unable to see any clue how to do the same directly.
Even by keeping the different regions' probability values in mind, it seems quite difficult to construct.
Edit: the clue seems in the form, which points to radius being needed of a particular region. This should aptly make use of the numbering of the regions from outside to inside.
The radius of a ring should be: $\frac{(6-i)r}{5},$ where $r$ is the radius of dart board, leading to the region 1 having radius of: $r.$
Then, finding the area of a region by subtracting the area of the circle below it, will get the same formula as given.
Had the numbering of the regions in reverse, i.e. the outermost region having number $5,$ then the radius of the regions are given by: $\frac{ir}{5}.$
The area of a region, with i-th label, would be then given by: $\pi.( (\frac{ir}{5})^2 - (\frac{(i-1)r}{5})^2 ) = \pi.\frac{-r^2+2ir^2}{5^2}$
The probability, for dart hitting in region $i$ would be, for a 'naive player' (a term which appears in the text (& shown in the image link), and should mean: the player assuming equal chances of dart falling anywhere on the board, which is a naive assumption):
(Area of $i$-th region) / (area of dart board) = $\frac{(-r^2+2ir^2)}{5^2.r^2} = \frac{-1+2i}{5^2}.$

It is not clear what you have in mind. the formula you have written is correct, by expanding the numerator, it simplifies to $$P(i)= \frac{11-2i}{25}, i =1, 2, \cdots,5$$

Good job solving the problem.
Let me generalize the formula

Given a dartboard, of radius 'r', with $k$ concentric circles, with numbering starting from the outermost one, from 1. The distance between each ring is $r/k$.

The outermost circle has radius $r$, the second outermost circle has radius $r-\frac{r}{k}$, the third outermost circle circle has radius $r-\frac{2r}k$. In general, the $i$ outermost circle has radius $r-\frac{(i-1)r}{k}=\left( \frac{k+1-i}{k}\right)r$. Notice that the $(k+1)$-th circle which doesn't exist has radius $0$.
The area of the $i$-th region can be obtained by using the area of the $i$-th circle subtract away the $(i-1)$-th circle.  Hence the probability of hitting $i$-th region is
$$\frac{\pi r^2 [\left( \frac{k+1-i}{k}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{k+1-(i+1)}{k} \right)^2]}{\pi r^2}=\frac{(k+1-i)^2-(k-i)^2}{k^2}$$
where $i=1, \ldots k$ which is consistent with the formula.
